# get number value between two strings using regex

Tags: regex, sed, sh

I have a string with multiple value outputs that looks like this:

```
SD performance read=1450kB/s write=872kB/s no error (0 0), ManufactorerID 27 Date 2014/2 CardType 2 Blocksize 512 Erase 0 MaxtransferRate 25000000 RWfactor 2 ReadSpeed 22222222Hz WriteSpeed 22222222Hz MaxReadCurrentVDDmin 3 MaxReadCurrentVDDmax 5 MaxWriteCurrentVDDmin 3 MaxWriteCurrentVDDmax 1
```

I would like to output only the read value (1450kB/s) using bash and sed.
I tried

```
 sed 's/read=\(.*\)kB/\1/'
```

but that outputs read=1450kB but I only want the number.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: the output you got doesn't seem right.. for ex: `echo 'SD performance read=1450kB/s write=872kB/s no error' | sed 's/read=\(.*\)kB/\1/'` will give `SD performance 1450kB/s write=872/s no error`

Comment: to get only the number, try `sed 's/.*read=\([0-9]*\)kB.*/\1/'`

Comment: If you need `awk` use this  `awk '{print $3}' test.txt | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample input shortened for demo:

```
$ echo 'SD performance read=1450kB/s write=872kB/s no error' | sed 's/read=\(.*\)kB/\1/'
SD performance 1450kB/s write=872/s no error

$ echo 'SD performance read=1450kB/s write=872kB/s no error' | sed 's/.*read=\(.*\)kB.*/\1/'
1450kB/s write=872

$ echo 'SD performance read=1450kB/s write=872kB/s no error' | sed 's/.*read=\([0-9]*\)kB.*/\1/'
1450
```

- Since entire line has to be replaced, add `.*` before and after search pattern
- `*` is greedy, will try to match as much as possible, so in 2nd example it can be seen that it matched even the values of `write`
- Since only numbers after `read=` is needed, use `[0-9]` instead of `.`

Answer (score 1):

Running

```
sed 's/read=\(.*\)kB/\1/'
```

will replace `read=[digits]kB` with `[digit]`. If you want to replace the whole string, use

```
sed 's/.*read=\([0-9]*\)kB.*/\1/'
```

instead.

As Sundeep noticed, sed doesn't support non-greedy pattern, updated for `[0-9]*` instead